# accessing list from json and iterating in postgres

Tags: postgresql-9.6

I have a json as mentioned below,

```
{
    "list": [{
            "notificationId": 123,
            "userId": 444
        },
        {
            "notificationId": 456,
            "userId": 789
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to write a postgres procedure which interates through the list and perform either update/insert based on notification id is already present or not in DB.

I have a notification table which has notificationid and userID as columns.

Can anyone please tell me on how to perform this using postgres json operators.

Comment: Do you have a unique index (primary key) for `notificationid`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE col->'list'@>'[{"notificationId":123}]';
```

You may replace the value `123` with whatever `notificationId` you want to search.  Follow the link below for a demo showing that this logic works:

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a unique constraint on `notificationid` (e.g. because it's the primary key, there is no need for stored function or loop:

```
with data (j) as (
  values ('
  {
      "list": [{
              "notificationId": 123,
              "userId": 444
          },
          {
              "notificationId": 456,
              "userId": 789
          }
      ]
  }'::jsonb)
)
insert into notification (notificationid, userid)
select (e.r ->> 'notificationId')::int, (e.r ->> 'userId')::int
from data d, jsonb_array_elements(d.j -> 'list') as e(r)
on conflict (notificationid) do update
   set userid = excluded.userid;
```

The first step in that statement is to turn the array into a list of rows, this is what:

```
select e.*
from data d, jsonb_array_elements(d.j -> 'list') as e(r)
```

does. Given your sample JSON, this returns two rows with a JSON value in each:

```
r                                     
--------------------------------------
{"userId": 444, "notificationId": 123}
{"userId": 789, "notificationId": 456}
```

This is then split into two integer columns:

```
select (e.r ->> 'notificationId')::int, (e.r ->> 'userId')::int
from data d, jsonb_array_elements(d.j -> 'list') as e(r)
```

So we get:

```
int4 | int4
-----+-----
 123 |  444
 456 |  789
```

And this result is used as the input for an `INSERT` statement.

The [`on conflict`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) clause then does an insert or update depending on the presence of the row identified by the column `notificationid` which has to have a unique index.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile i tried this,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_update_notifications(notification_ids jsonb) RETURNS void AS
$$
DECLARE
allNotificationIds text[];
indJson jsonb;
notIdCount int;
i json;
BEGIN

FOR i IN SELECT * FROM jsonb_array_elements(notification_ids)
  LOOP
    select into notIdCount count(notification_id) from notification_table where notification_id = i->>'notificationId' ;
    IF(notIdCount = 0 ) THEN
       insert into notification_table(notification_id,userid) values(i->>'notificationId',i->>'userId');
    ELSE
        update notification_table set userid = i->>'userId' where notification_id = i->>'notificationId';
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

END;
$$
language plpgsql;

select * from insert_update_notifications('[{
        "notificationId": "123",
        "userId": "444"
    },
    {
        "notificationId": "456",
        "userId": "789"
    }
]');
```

It works.. Please review this.